# How to assign a Group to a specific folder in a Document Library via Manage Access

Tags: sharepoint-online, document-library, permissions, administration, groups

From SharePoint Online, I have multiple document libraries.  Inside a specific one, I have 100's of folders.

I want to create a unique Group for a specific folder only inside this specific document library.

When I right click over the specific folder, I can see the latest feature of "Manage Access"...

[image]

I can easily go into it, then break inheritance, and grant access.

**But how do I create the group just for this folder, without it being associated anywhere else in my document library?**  We have 100's of folders in this single document library.

Here is the problem I see...When I go to the site level to create a group...

[image]

I didn't tell SharePoint I wanted this group assigned to every document library, but it did that anyway.  Instead, I want to create that group without it being assigned anywhere.  Then I will choose which document library, or folder to grant access for this group.  Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

1. Go to "Groups" page in your SharePoint site using the URL in below format:

```
https://contoso.sharepoint.com/sites/MySite/_layouts/15/groups.aspx
```

2. Click **New** to create a new group:

   [image]
3. Create a group by filling all information without assigning any permissions to the site:

   [image]
4. Now go to Manage Access - Advanced settings page for the specific folder in library, break inheritance, and grant access to newly created group.

Comment: ahhh - that is the trick!  to not assign any options at the bottom of the screen.  Many thanks for pointing that out!